# Место #PCDATA в смешанном содержимом в последовательности определений DTD

Tags: xml, xmlparser, dtd

В DTD можно определить, что элемент может содержать как *`#PCDATA`*, так и другие элементы. Такой тип содержимого называется смешанным (mixed). Для указания смешанного типа содержимого достаточно перечислить *`#PCDATA`* наряду с допустимыми дочерними элементами.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE DOCUMENT [
<!ELEMENT DOCUMENT (CUSTOMER)*>
<!ELEMENT CUSTOMER (NAME,DATE,ORDERS)>
<!ELEMENT NAME (LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME)>
<!ELEMENT LAST_NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT FIRST_NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DATE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ORDERS (ITEM)*>
<!ELEMENT ITEM (PRODUCT, NUMBER, PRICE)>
<!--mixed-->
<!ELEMENT PRODUCT (#PCDATA | PRODUCT_ID )*>
<!ELEMENT NUMBER (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PRICE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PRODUCT_ID (#PCDATA)>
]>
<DOCUMENT>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <NAME>
            <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
            <FIRST_NAME>Sam</FIRST_NAME>
        </NAME>
        <DATE>October 15, 2003</DATE>
        <ORDERS>
            <ITEM>
                <PRODUCT>Tomatoes</PRODUCT>
                <NUMBER>8</NUMBER>
                <PRICE>$1.25</PRICE>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <PRODUCT>
                    <PRODUCT_ID>
                        124829548702121
                    </PRODUCT_ID>
                </PRODUCT>
                <NUMBER>24</NUMBER>
                <PRICE>$4.98</PRICE>
            </ITEM>
        </ORDERS>
    </CUSTOMER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

Я обратил внимание при проверке корректности файла с помощью т.н. валидаторов (.NET XML Parser, MSXML SAX, MSXML DOM, Java build-in), что если *`#PCDATA`* находится в начале списка - проверка проходит. Если перед *`#PCDATA`* находится какой-либо элемент - появляются ошибки валидации (у каждого парсера свои, но суть одна и таже).

```
<?xml version = "1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE DOCUMENT [
<!ELEMENT DOCUMENT (CUSTOMER)*>
<!ELEMENT CUSTOMER (NAME,DATE,ORDERS)>
<!ELEMENT NAME (LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME)>
<!ELEMENT LAST_NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT FIRST_NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DATE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ORDERS (ITEM)*>
<!ELEMENT ITEM (PRODUCT, NUMBER, PRICE)>
<!-- mixed -->
<!-- ошибка. Почему? -->
<!ELEMENT PRODUCT (NUMBER | #PCDATA | PRODUCT_ID )*>
<!ELEMENT NUMBER (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PRICE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PRODUCT_ID (#PCDATA)>
]>
<DOCUMENT>
    <CUSTOMER>
        <NAME>
            <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
            <FIRST_NAME>Sam</FIRST_NAME>
        </NAME>
        <DATE>October 15, 2003</DATE>
        <ORDERS>
            <ITEM>
                <PRODUCT>Tomatoes</PRODUCT>
                <NUMBER>8</NUMBER>
                <PRICE>$1.25</PRICE>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                <PRODUCT>
                    <PRODUCT_ID>
                        124829548702121
                    </PRODUCT_ID>
                </PRODUCT>
                <NUMBER>24</NUMBER>
                <PRICE>$4.98</PRICE>
            </ITEM>
        </ORDERS>
    </CUSTOMER>

</DOCUMENT>
```

Почему в смешанном элементе *`#PCDATA`* должен находиться обязательно на первом месте?

Comment: Ответ "потому что так написано в [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content)" вас устроит?

Comment: @Roman Большое спасибо за ссылку!

К сожалению, там это не написано, что элемент ```#PCDATA``` должен быть всегда на первом месте. Поэтому, собственно, и возник вопрос. 

Как раз в спецификации приведено следующее:
```sh
 Mixed    ::=    '(' S? '#PCDATA' (S? '|' S? Name)* S? ')*'
   | '(' S? '#PCDATA' S? ')' ```
 - т. е. в спецификации как раз написано, что элемент данных ```S``` может находиться на первом месте (или не находиться - ```?```).

Есть, конечно примеры:
```sh
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA|a|ul|b|i|em)*>
<!ELEMENT b (#PCDATA)>
```
Но они не описывают все возможные варианты.

Comment: Может быть дело в несовершенстве парсеров? Есть куда развиваться. Не всё ещё реализовано.

Comment: Я разобрался. В спецификации ```S?``` - это пробельные символы. Теперь всё ясно!

Answer (score 0):

w3C спецификация §3.2.2. определяет смешанное содержание

```
[51]     Mixed      ::=      '(' S? '#PCDATA' (S? '|' S? Name)* S? ')*'
```

где `S` - это символы пробелов (т.н. white-space).